# ./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, sass, fonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ageya';
    src: url('./src/fonts/Ageya.otf'), format('otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ageya';
    src: url('./src/fonts/Ageya.ttf');
}
```

it shows the error

ERROR in ./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/App.scss) 5:36-85

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/fonts/Ageya.otf' in 'D:\project\linkstore\src'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Its sometimes when change the file  `alerted/rename/move` into another `files/folder` , you may find this error , try
`"npm rebuild node-sass"`
in your frontend code terminal, it might solve the issue

it will rebuild the dependencies successful

Answer (score 0):

Are you also doing that Free Code Camp React portfolio tutorial? I had this issue. You just need to make sure you have the actual font files in your /src folder.

You'll need to track down the "Ageya.otf" font file online and put it in your /src folder. You can google "free download ageya font". If it exists in a different format, just change the format appropriately.

For instance, if you find a download for "Ageya.ttf", you'll need to change:

```
src: url('./src/fonts/Ageya.otf'), format('otf');
```

to

```
src: url('./src/fonts/Ageya.ttf'), format('ttf');
```

Hope this is helpful!